# How to completely sanitize a string of illegal characters in python?

Tags: python, unicode

I have a feature of my program where the user can upload a csv file, which my program goes through and uses as input. I have one user complaining about a problem where his input is throwing up an error. The error is caused by there being an illegal character that is encoded wrong. The characters is below:

```
�
```

Sometimes it appears as a diamond with a "?" in the middle, sometimes it appears as a double diamond with "?" in the middle, sometimes it appears as "\xa0", and sometimes it appears as "\xa0\xa0".

In my program if I do:

```
print str_with_weird_char
```

The string will show up in my terminal with the diamond "?" in place of the weird character. If I copy+paste that string into ipython, it will exit with this message:

```
In [1]: g="blah��blah"
WARNING: 
********
You or a %run:ed script called sys.stdin.close() or sys.stdout.close()!
Exiting IPython!
```

notice how the diamond "?" is double now. For some reason copy+paste makes it double...

In the django traceback page, it looks like this:

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /chris/import.html
('ascii', 'blah \xa0 BLAH', 14, 15, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
```

The thing that messes me up is that I can't do anything with this string without it throwing an exception. I tried unicode(), I tried str(), I tried .encode(), I tried .encode("utf-8"), no matter what it throws up an error.

What can I do it get this thing to be a working string?

Comment: By the way, the reason you "can't do anything" with it is probably because all the things you tried involved typing expressions at the prompt.  The interactive interpreter displays the result of each expression by calling repr() on it.  Sometimes that leads to decode errors because your console doesn't handle Unicode (or other reasons?).  If you get such a thing, try assigning it to a dummy name (e.g. "x = foo" instead of just "foo") and that will usually not show an exception.  Then you know the exception is spurious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass, "ignore" to skip invalid characters in .encode/.decode
like `"ILLEGAL".decode("utf8","ignore")`

```
>>> "ILLEGA\xa0L".decode("utf8")
...
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 6: unexpected code byte

>>> "ILLEGA\xa0L".decode("utf8","ignore")
u'ILLEGAL'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare the coding on the second line of your script. It really has to be second. Like

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8
```

This might be enough to solve your problem all by itself. If not, see str.encode('utf-8') and str.decode('utf-8').

Answer (score 2):

you can also use:

```
python3 -c "import urllib, sys ; print urllib.quote_plus(sys.stdin.read())";
```

taken from https://wiki.python.org/moin/Powerful%20Python%20One-Liners

** ps, in the website it's pointed to use python, but I tested in python3 and it works just fine

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it (at least in python2) is to use unicodedata.normalize:

```
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text).encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

decode('utf-8', 'ignore') will just raise exception.